# How to Filter a list of objects in Thymeleaf on an object Property

Tags: thymeleaf

I have tried searching on StackExchange and also looked at other places using Google and the Thymeleaf reference as well. It seems like the syntax below should work but it is not filtering the list based on condition given.

```
<th:block th:each="dayNumber :${#numbers.sequence(1,7)}">
     <p th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(storeHours.?[#this.dayOfWeek eq #dayNumber])}" th:text="${dayNumber}"></p>
</th:block>
```

In above, we are trying to do a pretty simple filter. The `storeHours` is a list of Store Hours object. Each object has a property called `dayOfWeek`. It is an integer. In above, I am trying to simply print the missing day number. However, it is printing all 7 days.

I am sure I am missing something very basic here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think answer that I posted and deleted not appropriate for your question.. Strange, but in [the official tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#lists) where are no information about this feature. Frankly, I saw this feature for the first time :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<th:block th:each="dayNumber :${#numbers.sequence(1,7)}">
    <p th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(storeHours.?[dayOfWeek.equals(dayNumber)])}" th:text="${dayNumber}"></p>
</th:block>
```

Maybe you need to check your `storeHours` is NOT empty?
Then `${not #lists.isEmpty(...)}`.

Comment: Thanks, why would the filter not work? Is there some difference between equals implementation and eq in filter?

Comment: Thank you. The code that you posted works. We don't need "not" because if the condition matches then the list will not be empty and we need to print in this case. It is interesting because  "#this.dayOfWeek eq dayNumber" throws exception.